# horizontal touchpad scolling in flex/flash/actionscript

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a skinnable container that is bigger than my screen. I want to make the scrollbars invisible - which works - and further use the mousewheel and touchpad for horizontal and vertical scrolling. The MOUSE_WHEEL mouseevent works great for vertical scrolling, triggered by the mouse wheel and the touchpad vertical move. 
I am not able to listen to the horizontal touchpad scroll event. Is there a offical way to do so or a work around?

EDIT: I found a custom public class on this page: http://blog.hiraash.org/2010/08/09/finally-touchpad-and-mouse-wheel-scrolling-for-your-flash-application/. Unfortunately I was not able to make it work until now. As well I am still not sure if this hack is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the hardware and OS version, but you could give multitouch gesture events a try:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#supportedGestures

Here's a good starter: http://lucamezzalira.com/2009/12/02/multitouch-with-actionscript-3-and-air-2-0/

But it probably will only work on touchpads and only on new devices.

Comment: thank you. just did a test - here are the result for my laptop with a touchpad: var a:Vector.<String> = Multitouch.supportedGestures Result is null, var b:Boolean = Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents - false, var c:Boolean = Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents, result is false. So I guess this will not work